# How to get future date if i have the past date and the number of months after which i want the date?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am working on a Project in which i have a date(i.e 01-01-2013) on which a item was taken on lease for some months like 60, 70 months. It is different for different customers. I want to send a email to all the customers to renew the lease whose lease date is going to be end after 2 days. I am not able to get the expiration date of lease. I have the date on which the lease item was taken and the number of months for which it was taken. I am doing this in mysql. Can anyone help how can i do this.

Comment: Not sure if this function works in MySQL :- but you can add the lease months to the taken date like DATEADD(month, 70, TakenDate)AS Expirationdate. This works in MS SQL. Im sure this could lead you to the right direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use [DATE_ADD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)
where you add lease duration to lease start date
that will result in end-lease-date
then subtract [DATE_SUB()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) 2 days from that

to get end lease date:

```
select DATE_ADD(lease_start,INTERVAL 60 MONTH)
```

to get end lease date - 2 days

```
select DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(lease_start,INTERVAL 60 MONTH), INTERVAL 2 DAY) as alertDate
```

Comment: I am using like this DATE_ADD(fld.`Delivery Date`,INTERVAL fld.`Term` MONTH) as `Expiration Date` but it is giving null in the field. My Delivery Date is like '11/19/2013' and `Term` is 12. Is there any error in this.

Comment: i am not sure, several checks to do, 1) is fld.DeliveryDate dataType Date or DateTime, make sure its NOT char or varcahr, 2) you may need to format the  fld.DeliveryDate before passing it to the function 4) maybe you need to use Date(fld.DeliveryDate) as parameter input, try to test my query using hardcoded date like '2014-09-25 17:22:52' as input if results are good, then its one of the points above

Answer (score 2):

Here is the function you're looking for:

```
DATE_ADD(taken_date,INTERVAL nb_months MONTH)
```

This function will give you the expiration date corresponding to the `taken_date` on which i add the desired number of months.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

It gies the resulet as BLOB when written only this:

```
DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(fld.`Delivery Date`, '%m/%d/%Y'),
INTERVAL fld.`Term` MONTH) as `Expiration Date`
```

We have to cast it to date like this;

```
DATE(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(fld.`Delivery Date`, '%m/%d/%Y'),
INTERVAL fld.`Term` MONTH)) as `Expiration Date`
```